# jQuery select a single Div that shares class with others

Tags: jquery, class, jquery-selectors, parent-child

I really hope you can help me as I searched through several other questions but no solution helped me. The problem is: I'm building a portfolio site where clicking on one div opens a bigger div with more info. Those smaller divs share the same class - how am I able to tell jQuery to only add a class to the div with the 'trigger' in it?

My Javascript looks like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#moreinfo').addClass('hidden');
$('.portfoliotile p').addClass('hidden');
$('.portfoliotile h1').addClass('hidden');

 $('.trigger').click(function(){
            $('#moreinfo').removeClass('hidden');
            $(this).parent().addClass('dark');
        });

$('#closegall').click(function(){
            $('#moreinfo').addClass('hidden');
            $('.portfoliotile').removeClass('dark');
        });
});
```

I really hope you can help me, feel free to have a look at [THIS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mleyendecker/632Fw/34/)

Answer (score 1):

You want to alter the ancestor relative to *this* as, inside the handler, *this* is the element clicked:

You should normally use `closest` instead of `parent` as it is more tolerant to DOM/layout changes.

e.g.

```
    $(this).closest('.portfoliotile').addClass('dark');
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/632Fw/164/

As jQuery supports hiding and showing, I would suggest using its methods (`hide`/`show`, `fadeIn`/`fadeout`, `slideDown`/`slideUp` etc).